# Is a determiner, some or four, needed?

Tags: determiners, countability

If there are 5 boys, 4 boys eat chicken, and 1 boy doesn't eat chicken, is saying just 'boys eat chicken' wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just saying "boys eat chicken" is more towards the meaning of "all boys eat chicken", so I will recommend that you say:

> Most boys eat chicken.

In your case, or you could also say:

> Some boys eat chicken.

Or just simply say:

> Four out of five boys eat chicken.

Thanks to @PrimeMover, he came up with another idea:

> Of these 5 boys, 4 eat chicken.

Comment: Only strictly accurate to say: "Of these 5 boys, 4 eat chicken."

Comment: @PrimeMover Oh thanks for reminding me, edited mine :-)